# If distinct count reaches 10 in column then just return true/false instead checking laks of rows in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

//Actually it iterates through laks of columns for distinct rows it is costlier approach because I need to check if distinct count reaches 10 then return true/false.

```
    val distcnt = dfFilter.select(dfFilter.col("colName")).distinct().count()

    if (distcnt > 10) {
      //I need to do stuff here if it greater than 10 distinct rows
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Costly or not its the only approach, distinct count will not be interrupted in between with some condition it will iterate through the whole column and then return a distinct count value and there is no alternative approach as well as per my knowledge but if somebody knows any alternative will be glad to know.

Comment: I think we can use rdd and add column values one by one as distinct if it reaches 10 then return true/false

Comment: RDDs are slower than data frames so if possible try to avoid them until necessary

Answer (score 0):

If your count condition is always 10, then you can limit the rows returned before count function,

```
val distcnt = dfFilter.select(dfFilter.col("colName")).distinct().limit(11).count()
```

Comment: that will check the random 11 values so that will give the wrong result

Comment: Here, you are distinct all column rows then making limit. it is same as question only. please try udf and add one by one records in Set collection once it reaches then return true/false. I am not aware of udf so can u send code by making it executable code.

Comment: What's needed : count of distinct values of a column ['colName' here] and check if the count is greater than 10. That's what your code snippet tells me. Correct if I am wrong.